# Consulta controle de acesso wordpress via mysql

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Estou fazendo a migração de um site em wordpress e preciso consultar o controle de acesso aos posts para adicioná-los ao novo CMS, o site usa o plugin [User Access Manager](https://github.com/GM-Alex/user-access-manager) para fazer o controle de acesso aos posts. Tenho que fazer a consulta direto no banco de dados.

Comment: E qual problema está enfrentando? O que você já tentou?

Comment: Não conseguir encontrar as ligações entre os posts e regra de quem pode visualizar, não achei nada nas tabelas ainda... @MatheusReis